# Rotate Mapbox Map depending of the phone current orientation

Tags: android, android-mapview, mapbox

I'm trying to rotate the map to always face the direction we are moving towards to with **MapBox** Android. Currently, this is what I tried without success:

This is where I initialize the `mapbox` map:

```
mapView.getMapAsync(mapboxMap -> {
    Log.d(TAG, "Map is initialized");
    map = mapboxMap;
    map.getTrackingSettings().setMyBearingTrackingMode(MyBearingTracking.COMPASS);
});
```

And this is where I enable the location;

```
private void enableLocation(boolean enabled) {
    map.setMyLocationEnabled(enabled);
    if (enabled) {
        locationServices.addLocationListener(location -> {
            if (location != null) {
                // Move the map camera to where the user location is

                if (location.getBearing() != 0) {
                    map.setCameraPosition(new CameraPosition.Builder()
                            .target(new LatLng(location))
                            .bearing(location.getBearing())
                            .build());
                } else {
                    map.setCameraPosition(new CameraPosition.Builder()
                            .target(new LatLng(location))
                            .build());
                }
                Log.e(TAG, "location bearing:" + location.getBearing());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

---

### I ended up using this on the last version of MapBox:

```
mapView.getMapAsync(mapboxMap -> {
    Log.d(TAG, "Map is initialized");
    map = mapboxMap;
    map.getTrackingSettings().setMyBearingTrackingMode(MyBearingTracking.TRACKING_FOLLOW);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of the SDK are you using? I [merged a compass listener fix](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/pull/5877) last month that fixed the compass bearing tracking. You can read more about the [issue here](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/5861). Try updating to `4.2.0-beta.3` and use the first snippet you posted in your question. Let me know if this is the fix you were looking for!

Comment: I did, but the log is being polluted by message when I'm using it, which make it hard to develop and debug using it...

Comment: See my other post here for that other issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39706695/ignore-mapbox-unnecessary-logging-on-version-4-2-0-beta-3

Comment: We are aware of this issue, you can always filter out these messages in logcat. Here's a [pull request](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/pull/6452) we are working to merge right now.

Comment: I had to modify slightly the first snippet to make it work, for those that will face the same problem you should use this setting instead : **MyLocationTracking.TRACKING_FOLLOW**

Comment: There is also that log appearing: *A connection to https://events.mapbox.com/ was leaked. Did you forget to close a response body?*